# How do i fix Invalid arguments passed in DefaultMailSystem->format() (line 23 system.mail.inc

Tags: 7, emails

I'm getting this error while developing a module:

> Warning: Invalid arguments passed in DefaultMailSystem->format() (line 23 /modules/system/system.mail.inc)

here's my code:

```
function mymod_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'job_mail':
            $message['subject'] = 'mysubject';
            $message['body'][] = 'test';
            break;
    }
}
```

I googled it normaly this happens when `$message['body']` is defined like this:
`$message['body'] = 'test';` instead of `$message['body'][] = 'test';`

And then I've got the following code to call the above hook_mail()

```
function mymod_send_mail($vacancies, $user) {
    // specify module name and template key for hook_mail
    $module = 'mymod';
    $key = 'job_mail';

    // Specify to and from addressses.
    $to = 'my@email.com'; // user email TODO get user email based on $uid
    $language = language_default();
    $params = array(
        'username' => $user->name, 
        'sitename' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'), 
    $from = variable_get('site_mail', 'default@email.com');
    $send = TRUE; // defaul = TRUE can be set to FALSE to not actually send the mail and only generate it.
    drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send );
}
```

I've put a `debug()` in system.mail.inc above the implode function but that showed my message  `$message['body']` was not an array ( `$message['body'][]` ) anymore.

Also when I put a debug on the result of the drupal_mail function I see that my subject is set but the body is empty.

Comment: Perhaps try with `$language = language_default('language');` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using:

```
$language = user_preferred_language($user);
```